# how to clear contact form

Tags: html, css, input

I want my contact form to be cleared if message is sent. I am using following code to clear form

```
$('#contactForm').find('[name]').val('')
```

but i am also using HTML `required` attribute to make these fields REQUIRED. The problem is, when i clear form, all `required` fields get RED border like this.[image]

How to get rid of this

Comment: Check out [DOM `reset` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset) and [CSS `:invalid` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid).

Comment: can u describe this method more clearly. Please

Comment: Try $('#contactForm')[0].reset();

Comment: throws this in console `SyntaxError: missing name after . operator
 

$('#contactForm').[0].reset()`

Comment: A typo. should be $('#contactForm')[0].reset();

Comment: but this worked ` $('#contactForm')[0].reset();` thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can very well use the built-in [`.reset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid) function. You just need to do this:

```
$('#contactForm').find('[name]').each(function () {
  $(this).val('');
  this.reset();
  $(this).get(0).reset();
});
```

In your comment, it is not:

```
$('#contactForm').[0].reset()
// --------------^
```

The above is wrong! You have to do this for the object. Remove the `.`. So your code will be for resetting the full form (either one of the below):

```
$('#contactForm')[0].reset();
$('#contactForm').get(0).reset();
```

Comment: @NafeesAnwar Welcome! :)